# Adding references to a class to act as accessors

Tags: c++, reference

I have added reference variables to a class to act as accessors for an array which is declared as a private member. Basically, I have something like

```
class someClass {
private:
    int a[3];
public:
    int &a0;
    int &a1;
    int &a2;
    someClass() : a0(a[0]), a1(a[1]), a2(a[2]) {}

    someClass& operator=(const someClass &other) {
        std::memcpy(a, other.a, sizeof(a));
        return *this;
    }
};
```

However, it does not work as expected always. What am I missing here? Is there a better way to access elements of `a` as `.a0`, `.a1`, etc.

Comment: What is the behaviour you get and what is that you expect? "does not work as expected always" is pretty vague...

Comment: 1. How does it "not work?" 2. Why do you even bother? If you give public access to the thing anyway, just make `a` public and be done with it.

Comment: This seems to be an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), i.e. you have a solution you want to use, and ask us about how to make it work, but you don't tell us what *problem* you try to solve with your solution. Can you please explain *why* you would want something like this?

Comment: I created an object of the class, initialised it with some values and simply tried to make a vector of 10 copies. Some of the objects were copied correctly whereas others had junk in `a`.

Comment: The reason I want this is because I am mimicking the vector datatypes in OpenCL which have accessors of the form `s0`, `s1`, etc.

Comment: Maybe its because you don't follow [the rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29)? Oh, and your copy-assignment operator is causing *undefined behavior*, what does it return?

Comment: sorry, forgot a line... i return `*this`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using references, you should consider using mixed in unions instead:

```
struct Vector3
{
   union {
      float a[3];
      struct { float x, y, z; };
      struct { float r, g, b; };
   };
};

// v.a[0] is an alias for v.x
Vector3 v = { 0.0f, 0.1f, 0.2f };

// you can see this clearly since they have the same address:
std::cout << (&v.a[0] == &v.x) << std::endl;
```

This should provide what you are actually looking to achieve.